# How can I find Facebook profile by using Facebook Id number?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I integrated my website with facebook login button where I can get profile name of someone and his or her facebook Id number.

But the problem I have now- how can I find the facebook profile of that facebook Id number? For example, when I login from my website with facebook account I get the following Id number: 2143806789165478 but if I try to access that Id number like this **https://web.facebook.com/profile.php?id=2143806789165478** I get the following message

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmrFM.png)

Please, can anyone help me know how I can get facebook profile by using facebook id number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has removed the possibility to directly link to a profile via the user id.

You now need to ask for the [`user_link`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_link) permission first, and once you got that, you can request the `link` field of the user profile, to get a URL containing a temporary token. You can use that URL to link to the user profile, it will then redirect to the real profile address.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Facebook id finder

[FB ID Finder](https://findmyfbid.in/)

I think it will be helpful for you.